# show a String as predict label in JavaCv

Tags: java, javacv

I'm developing a Face recognition from [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/OpenCVFaceRecognizer.java) using JavaCV 1.1, choose LBPH recognizer, when the program run shows the predicted image number from training folder.

for example: if folder contains the following images: steve1.png, steve2.png and judy3.png, judy4.png and the Person to classify is judy, prints

```
Predicted label: 4
```

That means the person is from judy4.png

**I would like to show "judy" as predict label.**

The method used for shows predicted label return an int, need to be a String

```
faceRecognizer.predict(personToClassify);
```

here's the code where the question is involved:

```
MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

    Mat labels = new Mat(imageFiles.length, 1, CV_32SC1);
    IntBuffer labelsBuf = labels.getIntBuffer();

    int counter = 0;

    for (File image : imageFiles) {
        Mat img = imread(image.getAbsolutePath(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        int label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\-")[0]);

        images.put(counter, img);

        labelsBuf.put(counter, label);

        counter++;
    }

    FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
    // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

    faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);

    int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(testImage);

    System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
```

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with OpenCV, nor JavaCV. Just get the name from the filename that has the 4 in it.

Comment: But there's the problem, if files names are steve1.png, steve2.png and judy1.png, judy2.png. How might I know who of 2 persons is trying to  mean the number?

Comment: So maybe is the 4th name? It depends on which labels you used in your training

Comment: That uses faceRecognizer.predict(testImage) that return a int but I doesn't know any other method for return a string with the name(could be filename) of the person indentity from data base

Comment: Read about the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need to change the `predict` method. Just, when you parse the label, store also the name into a vector. Then just search the index of the label in `labelsBuf`, and get the name at the same index.

Comment: Ok, I'll test it, Thanks you, i will let you know if appers error.

Comment: Done! It's working! yay, I used System.out.println("Predicted label: " + fileName[predictedLabel]) and prints file name: -judy2.png. now I just need to add a data base with person names within to compare file name to return person name. Thanks you again!